# How to use a function containing eval in a file by variable defined at another file from that another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

Assume, I have created an python file (FirstFile.py) name which contains many functions and other things. One of the function is this (of course, it is simplified):

```
def func(string):
    assert eval(string)
```

Besides, I have created an python file which imports func() from the file mentioned above. Then this second python file try to execute following process:

```
from FirstFile import func
amk = 1
func("amk == 1")
```

When variable "amk" is in the first file, no problem reveals. However, when variable "amk" is in the second file, which is illustrated here, an error reveals:

```
NameError: name 'amk' is not defined
```

Would you like to please help me solve this problem?

Comment: is it `amk` or `ask` because your error shows `ask` but either way the variable is in the scope of the second file and the first would not have access. in order to give the first file access I would pass it as a variable into func(). where func is defined as `def func(string, *args):`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter It does not work with `def func(string, *args)` either.

Comment: @Kivi Kivit Can you elaborate on what you need to execute? The problem with the scope of variables could be solved somehow else if needed...

Comment: Sorry I meant **kwargs, where the key was the value you were trying to access and the value was the value. Not sure if this would work either. I would recommend taking some time to research scope!

Comment: it is `amk` not `ask`. I have just edited and corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `eval` executes in the current local/global scope, if you want to specify a different environment you can do something like:

```
eval("x == 1", {"x":1})
```

so your function could take an optional `environ` argument:

```
def func(string, environ=None):
    assert eval(string, environ)
```

then you can call the function from the other module passing `locals()` as the environment:

```
from FirstFile import func
amk = 1
func("amk == 1", locals())
```

As a side note I'd recommend against evaluating arbitrary code especially if it is coming from another source / module as it could accidentally contain harmful code.

Comment: The `if` statement in `func` is not necessary. Passing `None` as the globals arguments to `eval` will work as well.

Comment: so you are right, I wasn't sure and know there are other builtin functions that complain when given None.

Comment: Also, depending on the concrete problem of the question author, it might make sense to pass both globals and locals. It only makes a difference if `func` isn't called from module level, though.

Comment: Possibly but assuming the OP is using python3.5 you can use `{**globals(), **locals()}` to combine the two if absolutely needed, I feel like only using one namespace covers nearly all use cases though, so taking both namespaces would just add noise.