# How to edit global variable in module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am writing a Python module and I have a function that defines a new variable in the module. I want to set a variable that can be accessed in the file that is importing the file. If that is confusing, here is my code:

```
# main.py

import other_module

other_module.set_variable("var1")

print(other_module.var1) # This is not a NameError

print(var1) # NameError
```

However, if I do something *slightly* different:

```
# main.py

from other_module import *

set_variable("var1")

print(var1) # NameError

print(other_module.var1) # NameError
```

And `other_module.py`:

```
#     other_module.py

def set_variable(name):
    exec("""
global %s
%s = 5
         """ % (name, name))
```

I have no control over `main.py`. That is thr consumer's code. I want to be able to access and change `main.py`'s globals. I want this to work:

```
# main.py

from other_module import *

set_variable("var")

print(var) # This should print 5
```

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534046

Comment: Why are you using exec instead of just `globals()`?

Comment: @BrenBarn How would I use `globals()`? `globals().append`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing sounds like class method behavior to me.
A class will be safer to use than the global namespace, try a class?

This works:

```
# other.py
class Other(object):

    @classmethod
    def set_variable(cls, name):
        exec('Other.%s = 5' % name)

# main.py
from other import Other

Other.set_variable('x')
print Other.x

# output
% ./main.py
5
```